# Error while converting image file from AWS S3 Object to Base64

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I am using the below code for parsing S3 object into Base64 string.

```
InputStream is = s3Object.getObjectContent().getDelegateStream();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
String base64Data = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes); //Java Util lib.
```

This code works fine for text and pdf file. But while converting image files I am getting error MIME type not supported.

I also tried to use AWS and Apache Commons Base64 lib. still it is not working.

```
Base64.encodeAsString(bytes) //AWS
Base64.encodeBase64String(bytes) //Apache Commons
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS Java SDK  2

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;

import java.io.IOException;

public class S3ReadImg {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder()
                .region(Region.EU_WEST_1) //
                .build(); // Might change for you

        GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
                .bucket("my_bucket_name")
                .key("four.bmp") // also tested for image types png, jpg, gif
                .build();

        byte[] objectResponse = s3.getObject(getObjectRequest).readAllBytes();

        String encodedfile = new String(java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encode(objectResponse), java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GetObjectRequest request = GetObjectRequest.builder()
            .bucket("my_bucket_name")
            .key("four.bmp")
            .build();
    try {
        byte[] objectResponse = s3Client.getObject(request, ResponseTransformer.toBytes())
                .asByteArray();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(objectResponse);
    } catch (NoSuchKeyException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out issue was not in the code. API Gateway was not configured properly.

I referred this link
https://medium.com/swlh/upload-binary-files-to-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-with-aws-lambda-2b4ba8c70b8e